# Convert a Json String into JSONArray

Tags: java, arrays, json

I'm trying to create test data with a JSON String, however when I try to convert the string into a JSONArray, the test fails.

```
    String JSONString = "{\"Info\":[{\"area\":301336,\"nativeName\":\"Italia\",\"capital\":\"Rome\",\"demonym\":\"Italian\",\"flag\":\"https://restcountries.eu/data/ita.svg\",\"alpha2Code\":\"IT\",\"languages\":[{\"nativeName\":\"Italiano\",\"iso639_2\":\"ita\",\"name\":\"Italian\",\"iso639_1\":\"it\"}],\"borders\":[\"AUT\",\"FRA\",\"SMR\",\"SVN\",\"CHE\",\"VAT\"],\"subregion\":\"Southern Europe\",\"callingCodes\":[\"39\"],\"regionalBlocs\":[{\"otherNames\":[],\"acronym\":\"EU\",\"name\":\"European Union\",\"otherAcronyms\":[]}],\"gini\":36,\"population\":60665551,\"numericCode\":\"380\",\"alpha3Code\":\"ITA\",\"topLevelDomain\":[\".it\"],\"timezones\":[\"UTC+01:00\"],\"cioc\":\"ITA\",\"translations\":{\"br\":\"Itália\",\"de\":\"Italien\",\"pt\":\"Itália\",\"ja\":\"イタリア\",\"hr\":\"Italija\",\"it\":\"Italia\",\"fa\":\"ایتالیا\",\"fr\":\"Italie\",\"es\":\"Italia\",\"nl\":\"Italië\"},\"name\":\"Italy\",\"altSpellings\":[\"IT\",\"Italian Republic\",\"Repubblica italiana\"],\"region\":\"Europe\",\"latlng\":[42.83333333,12.83333333],\"currencies\":[{\"symbol\":\"\\u20ac\",\"code\":\"EUR\",\"name\":\"Euro\"}]}]}";
    JSONArray JSON = new JSONArray(JSONString);
```

The error is org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1]

Comment: what error do you get ? please explain the question properly with exact issue.

Comment: Sorry, I somehow forgot to type the error in. The error is "org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1]"

Comment: Try creating JSONObject as your string contains JSONObject. If you are converting the String to JSONArray the string should start with '[',but your string starts with '{'

Answer (score 0):

A `JSONArray` must starts always with `[`

You must to change your JSONString variable as follow:

**Solution 1:**

`[Info...` and so on

**Solution 2:**

Remove `Info` because it is typized element of your JSON array

Answer (score 0):

Your string represents a JSON Object, starting with "{". 
A JSONArray would begin with a "[".

If you parse the string into a JSONObject first, you should then be able to parse out your JSONArray from the "Info" key.

Just to elaborate on this in your case, something like this:

```
    String JSONString = "{\"Info\":[{\"area\":301336,\"nativeName\":\"Italia\",\"capital\":\"Rome\",\"demonym\":\"Italian\",\"flag\":\"https://restcountries.eu/data/ita.svg\",\"alpha2Code\":\"IT\",\"languages\":[{\"nativeName\":\"Italiano\",\"iso639_2\":\"ita\",\"name\":\"Italian\",\"iso639_1\":\"it\"}],\"borders\":[\"AUT\",\"FRA\",\"SMR\",\"SVN\",\"CHE\",\"VAT\"],\"subregion\":\"Southern Europe\",\"callingCodes\":[\"39\"],\"regionalBlocs\":[{\"otherNames\":[],\"acronym\":\"EU\",\"name\":\"European Union\",\"otherAcronyms\":[]}],\"gini\":36,\"population\":60665551,\"numericCode\":\"380\",\"alpha3Code\":\"ITA\",\"topLevelDomain\":[\".it\"],\"timezones\":[\"UTC+01:00\"],\"cioc\":\"ITA\",\"translations\":{\"br\":\"Itália\",\"de\":\"Italien\",\"pt\":\"Itália\",\"ja\":\"イタリア\",\"hr\":\"Italija\",\"it\":\"Italia\",\"fa\":\"ایتالیا\",\"fr\":\"Italie\",\"es\":\"Italia\",\"nl\":\"Italië\"},\"name\":\"Italy\",\"altSpellings\":[\"IT\",\"Italian Republic\",\"Repubblica italiana\"],\"region\":\"Europe\",\"latlng\":[42.83333333,12.83333333],\"currencies\":[{\"symbol\":\"\\u20ac\",\"code\":\"EUR\",\"name\":\"Euro\"}]}]}";

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSONString);
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Info");
```